# XPATH based content extraction from html pages

Tags: java, sax, xpath

I m trying to extract content based on given xpath. When it is just one element i want to extract, there is no issue. When I have a list of items matching that xpath, then i get the nodelist and i can extract the values.

However, there are a couple items related to each other forming a group, and that group repeats itself.

One way I could do is to get the nodelist of parent node of all such groups and then apply SAX based parsing technique to extract information. But this would introduce pattern specific coding. I want to make it generic.
ex.

```
<html><body>
<!--... a lot divs and other tags ... -->
<div class="divclass">
<item>
     <item_name>blah1</item_name>
     <item_qty>1</item_qty>
     <item_price>100</item_price>
</item>
</div>
<div class="divclass">
<item>
     <item_name>blah2</item_name>
     <item_qty>2</item_qty>
     <item_price>200</item_price>
</item>
</div>
<div class="divclass">
<item>
     <item_name>blah3</item_name>
     <item_qty>3</item_qty>
     <item_price>300</item_price>
</item>
</div>
</body></html>
```

I could easily write code for **this** xml but not a generic one which could parse any given specification.

I should be able to create a `list` of `map` of `attribute-value` from above.

Has anyone tried this?

**EDIT**
List of input xpaths:

```
1. "html:div[@class='divclass']/item/item_name"
2. "html:div[@class='divclass']/item/item_qty"
3. "html:div[@class='divclass']/item/item_price"
```

Expected output in simple text:

```
 item_name:blah1;item_qty:1;item_price:100
 item_name:blah2;item_qty:2;item_price:200
 item_name:blah3;item_qty:3;item_price:300
```

Key point here is, if I apply each xpath separately, it would fetch me results vertically, i.e. first one will fetch all item_names, second will fetch all qtys. So I'll loose the co-relation within these pieces.

Hope this clears my requirements.

Thanks
Nayn

Comment: Does anyone know of a good way to achieve this?

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at, but can you provide an example of the output you want to see?
E.g. you said "I could easily write code for this xml but not a generic one which could parse any given specification." If you show us this specific code, that would help a lot toward understanding what it is you want and how to generalize it.

Comment: Nopes. I thought XQuery and XPath fall on the same line. Let me see now.

Comment: @jaxvy could you please list your answer so that i can offer you the bounty. Could you give me good open source XQuery implementations?

Comment: My use case is exactly what is listed here. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp03225.html?ca=dgr-jw26XQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think XQuery is a great solution for screen scraping. You can use the [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) processor for executing your xqueries. Moreover, you can use [Piggy Bank](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Piggy_Bank) Firefox extension to easily find the XPath expressions, regarding the content you want to extract from a web page, that you can use within your xqueries.

Comment: Agreed, I've used XQuery to that effect in the past, and it works great. One will need to couple it with an HTML to DOM parser like Tidy if the parsed HTML comes "from the wild".

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I got your question, but it sounds like you want to use XPath on HTML documents.

To use XPath, the HTML document being prased needs to be well-formed. There are several HTML parsers for Java; [this article](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/java-html-parsing-library-comparison/) compares 4 of them.

[HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php) seems to provide what you are after. It allows a subset of XPaths to be performed on "cleaned-up" HTML documents. Apparently it doesn't support the full set of XPath expressions though, see [the documentation](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/doc/org/htmlcleaner/TagNode.html#evaluateXPath(java.lang.String)).

If you require more complex XPath expressions than what HtmlCleaner supports, you may need to use the [javax.xml.xpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) package with a well-formed XHTML document. [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/howto.html) can convert an HTML document to an XHTML one.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Does "html:div[@class='divclass']/item/*" give what you want?

Comment: It would list down all the nodes, I might want to fetch only a few. Also the hierarchy could any level deep.

Answer (score 1):

Why not apply XPath in two steps.

First an XPath(s) to get the records (the lines in your output):

```
//div[@class='divclass']/item
```

Then the XPath(s) to get the fields (the columns), relative to each record:

```
item_name
item_qty
item_price
```

Here's working code (in Javascript, Windows scripting), gives you the output you want:

```
var doc = new ActiveXObject("MSXML.DOMDocument");
doc.load("test.xml");

// XPATH #1
var recordXPath = "//div[@class='divclass']/item";
// XPATHS #2, in a dictionary ("field name":"XPath")
var fieldXPaths = { item_name : "item_name",
                    item_qty : "item_name",
                    item_price : "item_price" };

var items = doc.selectNodes(recordXPath);
for (var itemCtr = 0; itemCtr < items.length; itemCtr++) {
    var item = items[itemCtr];
    var fieldEntries = [];

    for (var fieldName in fieldXPaths) {
        var fieldXPath = fieldXPaths[fieldName];
        var fieldNode = item.selectSingleNode(fieldXPath);
        fieldEntries.push(fieldNode.tagName + ":" + fieldNode.text);
    }
    WScript.Echo(fieldEntries.join(";"));
}
```

Comment: Could you give me some example of nested xpaths and it's application? I thought the xpaths are applied on the whole document, it returns a Document object and then we've to walk through the nodelist to get the content/attribute/attribute-value etc.

Comment: XPaths can be applied to the document or relative to a node. See edit with code above

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to achieve and how it relates to XPath. If you want to map XML to Java objects then [JAXB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding) might help, but it is based on XML schemas, not on XPath.

Comment: The use case is for scraping diff web pages. The content in html will not be extractable by xml binders since it is not xml we are dealing with. Apologies if i have given that impression. Besides i don't want to write java code for every new page we scrape; it should as simple as writing xpaths in config for different contents and get the data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but I use XSLT to go go the other way from data to HTML. Seems to me that you just need to structure the XPATH execution a little and XSLT is good for this.